# "A resonant state unbound to neutron decay by at least 100 keV was identified" Could you guys please explain this clearly?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics

Does it mean that If we provide 100 KeV energy to the nucleus in that resonant state then it will decay through a neutron emission?

Comment: Without more context (or a cite of the paper) it is not completely clear. I would interpret it as the resonant state (an excited state) is 100keV above the state of the remnant nucleus plus a free neutron.

Comment: you should give a link. I think it is within the context of the links  of this answer  to a previouw question of yours https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/580842/difference-between-bound-and-unbound-nuclear-states/580866#580866

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it mean that If we provide 100 KeV energy to the nucleus in that resonant state then it will decay through a neutron emission

No, it means that there is an enhancement at 100KeV invariant mass when a neutron is scattered from the nucleus, i.e. the energy carried by the neutron is positive, as it is called unbound.  See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonances_in_scattering_from_potentials) in wikipedia for quantum mechanical resonances. [This article](http://homepage.cem.itesm.mx/fdelgado/ciencia/cadi/ref14.pdf) gives the math.